# Positioning divs on another div with centerX and centerY properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made this thing where I can spawn shapes and save them into JSON format. I calculated centerX and centerY and now I just want to be able to place these shapes back on the board in their original position with a load button. What property should I set exactly for centerX and centerY to position them?

This is how I made the JSON

```
document.getElementById('save-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var theBoard = document.getElementById('myBoard');
    var boardChildren = theBoard.children;
    var data = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < boardChildren.length; i++) {
        var selectedChild = boardChildren[i];
        var selectedChildID = selectedChild.id;
        var selectedChildStyle = window.getComputedStyle(selectedChild);
        data[selectedChildID] = {};

        var $child = $('#' + selectedChildID);
        var centerX = $child.offset().left + ($child.width() / 2);
        var centerY = $child.offset().right + ($child.height() / 2);

        data[selectedChildID].className = selectedChild.className;
        data[selectedChildID].borderRadius = selectedChildStyle.getPropertyValue("border-radius");
        data[selectedChildID].backgroundColor = selectedChildStyle.getPropertyValue("background-color");
        data[selectedChildID].height = selectedChildStyle.getPropertyValue("height");
        data[selectedChildID].width = selectedChildStyle.getPropertyValue("width");
        data[selectedChildID].marginLeft = selectedChildStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-left");
        data[selectedChildID].marginTop = selectedChildStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-top");
        data[selectedChildID].float = selectedChildStyle.getPropertyValue("float");
        data[selectedChildID].zIndex = selectedChildStyle.getPropertyValue("z-index");
    }

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t");

    var file = new Blob([jsonString], {
        type: 'application/json'
    });

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = 'data.json';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);

});
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything that is JSON here, nor do I see any reason why there should be.

Comment: If you want to *"place these shapes back on the board in their original position"*, then what's the point of `centerX` and `centerY`?

Comment: I didn't include the code that makes the json. These are just the properties I want in it. My question is when I am parsing the json, what do I set centerX and centerY to so it loads in the original position

Comment: *"what do I set centerX and centerY to so it loads in the original position"* That makes no sense. `centerX` and `centerY` are not the original position, so why would they be involved in setting the original position? Also, If your question mentions JSON, you should show it as well as ALL the other relevant code, like the HTML.

Comment: If you want to put something back where it originally was, then record the original position (via the `.top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` properties) before moving the element.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I read somewhere that you need the center position of the element

Comment: Setting top bottom left and right properties would do the same thing as if you were to set some center property.